# handeling orientation change in android

Tags: android, android-activity, orientation, onconfigurationchanged

I wanted to have a differnet look to one of my activities when the orientation changes.
I created the layout-land folder and added `activity1.xml` there but when I switch the orientation I still get the regular activity.

Is there anything else I need to do to make it work?

Thanks.

Comment: Is activity1.xml also the name of the file used in portrait mode?  You did this correctly (layout-land folder), so there must be something minor that you missed.  Did you make noticeable changes between the two layouts?

Comment: @Rich I named them exactly the same and yes the layouting is totally different. any other ideas?

Comment: I just did the same thing in an app I'm developing this week, so not sure why it's not working.  Is it possible that your layout-land folder is in the wrong place (not directly below res/)?  Is it possible that this activity is not handling orientation changes (set to portrait only in manifest)?  Post a screen of your package contents and maybe some of the manifest code?

Comment: @Rich Found my problem... i had 2 activities that were selected from code according to the data shown and I created a landscape page for only one of them... stupid :) Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have `android:configChanges` attribute defined in your manifest?

There are two ways the orientation change can be handled:

1. You define attribute `android:configChanges="orientation"` in your app's mainfest and implement `onConfigurationChanged()` in your activity. This method will then be called when orientation changes.
2. You do NOT define `android:configChanges` attribute. The you activity will be restarted (a new activity crated) and will go through a lifecycle process (onCreate, onStart, 
   etc), every time orientation of device changes.

Answer (score 0):

Read [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onConfigurationChanged%28android.content.res.Configuration%29) about configuration changes. You can override `onConfgiratationChanged()` method of your activity and set a content view to the activity1 layout.